# Make a single comment line bold

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, I would like to edit the font of a single comment within a block of comments. I don't want to change *all* of the comment lines in the class, but a single comment. For example, I want to make a first line in the comment block bold, to make it stand out as a title line.

The only method in Eclipse that I found that can change font (ex: make it bold or italicized, was Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring. This, however, affects all comments, and I cannot find a way to change a single comment.

Comment: Do you mean within the source file itself, or within the popup details, like when a class or function is hovered?

Comment: There is no way to change a single comment

Comment: Please create a change request for Eclipse JDT https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT

Comment: @PaulT. I meant within the Eclipse source file.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that Eclipse doesn't offer flexibility that granular, though limited markdown is available within some comments, but these are only rendered in the pop-up details not within the source file, where the markup tags appear in raw form.